# How to control the ALE virtual text color?

Tags: plugin-ale

The ALE virtual text for Error and Warning has the same color than the comment.

[image: ALE screen shot]

I would like to have a different colors to identify the ALE error more easily.

How to do that?

Comment: @user3342816, I posted a question and an answer to address the problem you addressed in the Vim chat. Let me know if I have understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of the ALE virtual text are controlled by the following five highlighting groups:

- `ALEVirtualTextError`
- `ALEVirtualTextWarning`
- `ALEVirtualTextInfo`
- `ALEVirtualTextStyleError`
- `ALEVirtualTextStyleWarning`

With the following command:

```
highlight ALEVirtualTextError guifg=red
```

You get red error messages:

[image]

You could also, as suggested @romainl, link to existing highlighting group to get a more consistent look:

```
highlight link ALEVirtualTextError Error
```

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1. I would do `highlight link ALEVirtualTextError Error` to insure consistency with the rest of the current colorscheme. 2. I would do it via a `ColorScheme` autocommand.